# Why does deleting the move constructor cause a compile error?

Tags: c++, gcc

The following code works OK:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct oops
{
        ~oops()
        {
                cout << " oops! " << endl;
        }
};

struct sample
{
        oops* x = nullptr;
        sample(oops* p) : x(p)
        {
                cout << "sample: " << p << endl;
        }
        ~sample()
        {
                delete x;
                cout << "destroy sample " << endl;
        }
        sample(const sample&)
        {
                cout << "copy sample " << endl;
        }
        sample(sample&&)
        {
                cout << "move sample " << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        sample s = new oops;
        return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
sample: 0x1470c20
 oops!
destroy sample
```

It clearly shows that neither the move nor copy constructor was called.
When these constructors are deleted,

```
sample(const sample&) = delete;
sample(sample&&) = delete;
```

gcc gives a compile error:

```
bpp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bpp.cpp:29:17: error: use of deleted function ‘sample::sample(sample&&)’
  sample s = new oops;
                 ^
bpp.cpp:24:2: note: declared here
  sample(sample&&) = delete;
  ^
bpp.cpp:14:2: note:   after user-defined conversion: sample::sample(oops*)
  sample(oops* p) : x(p)
  ^
```

Does this have anything to do with `-fno-elide-constructors`?
How can I compile it without defining these constructors or using an explicit constructor?

Edit:
My GCC verison is 5.4.0. The command is:

```
g++ bpp.cpp -std=c++17
```

Comment: What is GCC compiler version and options you are using to compile the code?

Comment: use `-std=c++17` to avoid these errors

Comment: GCC 5.4.0 does not implement the relevant parts of the C++17 Standard: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html. Look for _Guaranteed copy elision [P0135R1]_, which was introduced by GCC 7.

Comment: `sample s = new oops;` IMHO I would never do something like this in the context the question is doing it. Would confuse the hell out of reviewers (thinking you are initializing a base class `sample` with the derived type `oops`). Good question though :)

Answer (score 17):

```
sample s = new oops;
```

This is a form of [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). For a compiler to resolve it until C++17, a copy or move constructor must exist. However, a compiler is free to elide its call due to optimizations (with GCC and `-fno-elide-constructors`, the move constructor is called).

Since C++17, neither of these constructors is required: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3V8glnpqF5QxljJl.

---

> How can I compile it without defining these constructors or using explicit constructor?

Very simply, avoid *copy initialization* and use *direct initialization* instead:

```
sample s { new oops };
```

Or, use C++17.

Comment: Lots of thanks! In a special case, I have to use the "=" symbol in our project. And I do tried C++17, but also a compile error in GCC5.4, like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8HgD62a6NOSYwltQ.

Comment: Also, I can hardly understand that why it actually didn't call move constructor(no output), but need it be existed.

Comment: @Lizho Because the C++ 11/14 Standard says that it needs to exist. Optimizations (copy elision here) cannot change the language rules.

Comment: @Lizho If you want C++17, you need to use a compiler that implements it. It's not the case of GCC 5.4 (there is only a partial support).

Answer (score 6):

#### Why does this fail to compile?

This line of code:

```
sample s = new oops;
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
sample s = sample(new oops);
```

In C++11 and C++14, this implicitly calls the move constructor (or the copy constructor, if no move constructor is available). Because compilers are allowed to elide copies and moves, the actual move is elided, and it doesn't show anything when the move constructor is called. Even though the actual move is elided, programs aren't allowed to refer to deleted functions *even implicitly*, so there's a compiler error.

You can fix this by changing the initialization to either

```
sample s { new oops };
```

or

```
sample s ( new oops );
```

or, if you really wanna use `=`, you can take advantage of [temporary lifetime extension](https://abseil.io/tips/107) to write

```
// s won't get destroyed until the end of the scope
// it's safe to use s after this statement
sample&& s = new oops;
```

#### What does C++17 change?

C++17 made some changes to the set of value categories objects fall in. In C++17, `sample(new oops)` becomes a prvalue, and the c++17 standard mandates that compilers are required to yeet prvalues into place without copying it or moving them. This is done through a combination of dark magic and sorcery.

This means that
`sample s = new oops;`
is **legal** in c++17.

#### Why does it still fail to compile when you add `-std=c++17`?

**This code should compile under C++17**, and the error you're getting occurs because gcc 6.3 and earlier don't implement that part of the c++17 standard. **This issue was fixed in gcc 7.1** and the code will compile as expected.